# how to insert a data in json text file

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to insert a new piece of data in a text file.
This is the method I use to read the text file:

```cs
try
{
    var path = @"text file\\GetAllEmp.txt";
                
    string rawJson = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8);

    ObservableCollection<EmployeeItem> Employee = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeItem>();
    var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rawJson);

    List<EmployeeItem> emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmployeeItem>>(rawJson);

    listitem.ItemsSource = emp;
```

I just need to add new data in the text file.
How to add data?
What I have tried is:

```cs
public static void Writeemployee()
{
    var path = @"text file\\GetAllEmp.txt";

    string rawJson = File.ReadAllText(path);

    List<EmployeeItem> emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmployeeItem>>(rawJson);
    var abs = emp;
    for (int i = 0; i < abs.Count; i++)
    {
        EmployeeItem s_Item = new EmployeeItem();
        int SID = ((int)s_Item.SiteID);
        DataAccess.AddEmployee(s_Item);
    }
}
```

My data access:

```cs
public static async void AddEmployeee(EmployeeItem Employee)
{
}
```

I just don't know how to insert. If there is any other method to insert, please let me know.

Comment: I did my best to rescue the question, but you need to rephrase some sentences to make them make sense. Your Data Access snippet seems to be an empty method? Is that really the case?

Comment: It is all a bit convoluted, I am afraid. But to add one item in a json file, you do need to read it, deserialize the data, add the new item and then overwrite the file by serializing the new list to it. I'd highly recommend to either only load data at app start and write data on request or maybe every X minutes and/or on close **or** use an actual Database ( SQLite, LiteDB, ... ? ).

Comment: if you guys have any new idea to add a data please let me know i can change it

Comment: Well, first of all `var abs = emp;` doesn't really make sense? Why not use `emp` ? And why do you iterate the list anyway? You call the `AddEmployee` method for each item, but you do not add an actually _new_ one. And as `AddEmployee` seems to be empty, it does just nothing. I don't really know what to suggest, here.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't even iterate the list. It just loops for list size times ...

Comment: If you insist on using files, you'll probably want something along this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NGGqdX ( just that you'd read and write from and to a file instead of `Console.WriteLine` )

Comment: BTW: Both NewtonSoft and Text.Json have the ability to deserialize from a text file (that contains valid json) directly (well kind of - via FileStream).

Answer (score 0):

Using the file APIs in UWP **cannot** add items to the Json file without deleting the original items.

Because of the format of the Json file, items need to be placed in `[{items1},{items2 }]`, so you need to read all the items, then add new elements, convert the list to Json format and write it to the file.

Here is a code sample.

```
EmployeeItem employeeItem = new EmployeeItem
{
    Id = 8, 
    GroupID = 18,
    SiteID = 5565
};

StorageFolder appFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
string path = @"GetAllEmp.txt";

//get data
string rawJson = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8);
ObservableCollection<EmployeeItem> Employee = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeItem>();
var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rawJson);
List<EmployeeItem> emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmployeeItem>>(rawJson);


emp.Add(employeeItem);

StorageFile sampleFile = await appFolder.GetFileAsync(path);         
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emp));
```